# the right position of the passive reduced relative clause

Tags: grammar

I have seen the passive reduced relative clauses in different positions so far. How can I decide what position is appropriate for any of them ?

*Example 1 : She obtained measures of business students' desires for
**the perceived status** of their school.

Example 2 : ...This depends on the degree to which **the persons involved** are seeking self-enhancement or self-transcendence.*

Before the noun ? Or after the noun ? What determines its position ?

Comment: What passive reduced relative clause are you talking about? Incidentally, "involved" is not a verb but an adjective here.

Comment: I supposed that the phrases in bold were adjectives. I mean, I guessed "the persons involved" meant "the persons which are involved" and "are involved" was the passive structure. Similarly, I thought "the perceived status" meant "the status which was perceived". I really get confused now and I have two questions : First, how can the adjective "involved" is put after the noun ? Second, what determines the proper location of passive reduced relative clause ? (After or before the noun)